# How do I put a small text on top and on bottom of a word in a paragraph using css?

Tags: html, css

I wanna know how do I put a word on top and on bottom of a text using CSS? It's hard to put in words so I've made a rough image on what I really mean

[image: See here.]

As you can see, the "My name is Marwan and I am 20 years old." part is just the normal paragraph on a web page in large fonts, and uppertext and bottomtext is in small fonts and the words in the paragraph automatically makes the required space in between so that the uppertext and bottomtext are always aligned in the middle. The paragraph is however not aligned and is either LTR or RTL depending on the language.

I have no idea how I can successfully achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZzMjL

I just created a parent div with a `text-align: center;` and inside that div I created divs for each section of text. This will make sure all text is centered.

```css
.row-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row-middle {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-top">uppertext1</div>
  <div class="row-middle">My</div>
  <div class="row-bottom">bottomtext1</div>
</div>

<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-top">uppertext2</div>
  <div class="row-middle">Name</div>
  <div class="row-bottom">bottomtext2</div>
</div>

<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-top">uppertext3</div>
  <div class="row-middle">Is</div>
  <div class="row-bottom">bottomtext3</div>
</div>

<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-top">uppertext4</div>
  <div class="row-middle">Some</div>
  <div class="row-bottom">bottomtext4</div>
</div>

<div class="row-wrap">
  <div class="row-top">uppertext5</div>
  <div class="row-middle">Long Name</div>
  <div class="row-bottom">bottomtext5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot for your help :) However there's one more thing, if the paragraph is long and the div is of a fixed width then the paragraph continues to the second line but then the 2nd line is too close to the first one. Any idea how to make a space between the upper and bottom line? Ofcourse this is not an issue when the paragraphs are separate because I can easily create space using padding or margin but I have no idea about one single paragraph that continues to the second line because I’m working in a fixed width that is not so big.